# stokes theorem integral around a sphere and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Evaluate using Stokes theorem $$\int_\gamma ydx+zdy+xdz$$
where $\gamma$ is the curve given by $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2=z^2=2a^2$,$x+y=2a~~$, starting from $(2a,0,0)$ and then going below the z-plane.
$$$$ What i tried was i calculate $curl(\vec{V})=-(i+j+k)~~$. Then i calculated the unit norma as $\hat{n}=\dfrac{(x-a)\hat{i}+(y-a)\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Now $$\int\int_S(\nabla\times \vec{V})\cdot \hat{n}=\int\int_S(2a-x-y-z)dS=\int\int_R \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2}dxdy$$ where $R $ is the region bounded by the circle $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2=2a^2$
$$$$
 is this correct, if not please help. The problem with me using Stokes, Gauss theorems is that i am not able to handle the surfaces of integration, limits of integration. Please also suggest some books to make my understanding more clear

Comment: Do you mena the sphere: $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+z^2=2a^2$?

Comment: yes it's given like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the curve $\gamma$ lays in the plane $x+y=2a$, why don't you consider $S$ as the intersection disc (not the sphere cap) and take the unit norm $\hat{n}=\dfrac{\hat{i}+\hat{j}}{\sqrt{2}}$ which is constant? In this way
$$(\nabla\times \vec{V})\cdot \hat{n}=-(\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k})\cdot
\dfrac{\hat{i}+\hat{j}}{\sqrt{2}}=-\sqrt{2}.$$

Moreover, $\gamma$ is a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) of the sphere $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+z^2=2a^2$, because the centre $(a,a,0)$ belongs to the plane $x+y=2a$. Hence the disk $S$ such that $\partial S=\gamma$ has area $2\pi a^2 $. Finally, by [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem)
$$\int_\gamma ydx+zdy+xdz=\iint_S (\nabla\times \vec{V})\cdot \hat{n}dS=-\sqrt{2}|S|=-2\sqrt{2} \pi a^2.$$
Note that $\hat{n}$ induces the correct orientation on $\gamma$:
starting from $(2a,0,0)$ the path goes below the $z$-plane.

Comment: so the rgion of integration will be the region inside this great circle?

Comment: @Upstart Yes, and since we are integrating a constant, the  integral is just the constant multplied by the area of this great circle.

Comment: @Upstart Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes i have some doubt.First the integral left $dS$ is the surface integral ? And since the surface that we get is a disc then the surface area=area .and hence the  $dS $ becomes $dxdy $ only and not $\dfrac {dxdy}{\hat {n}\cdot\hat {k}}. $

Comment: @Upstart We now that $(\nabla\times \vec{V})\cdot \hat{n}=-\sqrt{2}$ therefore it remains, $\iint_SdS$ which is equal to $|S|$ (I'm not saying that $dS=dxdy$.

Comment: what is $|S|$. Surface area of a circle?

Comment: @Upstart Yes, $|S|$ is the area of the surface $S$.

Comment: area of the surface and since the surface is just a circle therefore just the area

Comment: @Upstart $S$ is a DISC whose boundary is the great CIRCLE $\gamma$.

Comment: yes i mean since it is just a disc so surface area becomes area?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: how did you figure out that unit normal vector will be to the surface and not to the sphere ,like i calculated? can you explain that a bit

Comment: You can use also the surface of the sphere, but it is not convenient. Actually any surface which has $\gamma$ as boundary is fine. I chose the plane because it is simpler.

Comment: ok. Thanx for the explainations Robert

Comment: @Upstart Well done, and thanks for the talk. BTW do you think that my answer was helpful in any way? Have you a result for this exercise that can be checked?

Comment: no i don't have answer but i think it's correct.